# Javascript not appearing correctly after adding a document type

Tags: php, javascript, html, xhtml

I am in the process of converting some poorly written html files to xhtml. In the html file, a javascript file is included which creates a navigation menu. When you mouse over something in the menu, a sub menu will appear just below.

My problem is, when I add a document type, all the submenus appear in the top left of the screen. Any ideas why that would be?

If needed, I can supply some source code, I just don't know whether to show the javascript code or the actual php file code.

Comment: Maybe the proper doctype brokes the poorly written css.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unlikely to be a Javascript problem. More likely it's an error in the HTML structure and/or css. Possibly some element which contains the menu is missing, or has lost its "position: relative" attribute, causing absolutely positioned menus to climb back up the DOM tree looking for a relative element, but finding only the document root.

Comment: I was looking at the menu and the code was written back in 1997. It does not even dynamically resize itself. For example, it tells the drop menus the exact pixels to appear. I think I am going to just create a new menu on my own.